# Passing Rails Parameters into Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, parameters

I'm trying to pass in two variables for a Nested Model form to use, but I'm getting an error.  It's probably an easy syntax error that someone experienced could see right away, but I don't see it.

I have a template showing users, if you click one, it should take the user_id and community _id for use in the form.  Both community and user are properly declared in the controller.

link to form:

```
<%= link_to "award badge", award_badge_badges_path, :user_id => user.id, :community_id => @community.id %>
```

The form uses two models - badge and badge winners.  The user_id and community_id are needed for badge_winners which is nested in badges.  The error I'm getting is `"undefined local variable or method 'user_id' for #<#<Class:0x77544c0>:0x7714230>"` so I think that something is wrong with the 2nd and 3rd lines in the form.  Here's the form:

```
<%= form_for(@badge) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id ,:value => user_id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :community_id ,:value => community_id %>
    <%= f.label :Description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>

<%= f.fields_for :badge_winners do |builder| %>
    <%= render "badge_winner", :f => builder, :locals => {:user_id => user_id, :community_id => community_id} %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit "Give Badge" %>
<% end %>
```

the show template in the controller:

```
def award_badge
  @badge = Badge.new
  badge_winners = @badge.badge_winners.build
end
```

the badge winner partial

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :user_id ,:value => user_id %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :community_id ,:value => community_id %>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the local variables passed to the form? Try outputting the values of `user_id` before constructing the form.

Comment: @Ekampp that was a good suggestion - i wasn't thinking. when i do that i get an error "undefined local variable or method `user_id' for #<#<Class:0xedeba88>:0xede80f8>".  it's true that user_id is not a part of the badge model (where the form is), it's a part of the nested model (badge_winner).  not sure how to correct this though.